# In Ruby on Rails, is there a way to say, try Product.find(12345) but don't error if not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For example, just have it return `nil` if not found, 
or must we always use `begin... rescue... end` to catch the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

> Product.find_by_id(12345)

. This would return nil and not error.

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rescue_from` to specify a method to use to handle the exception. If it's something that's used in multiple places this will help remove duplication. You could even put it in your application controller if it's used across controllers. Here are some examples: http://m.onkey.org/rescue-from-dispatching

Answer (score 0):

You could test it first with Product.exists?(12345)